# php_oci8_12c.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application)

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

Before someone marks it as a duplicate question, I'd like to say that I've tried most of the solutions exits on the internet, but none of them worked for me, even I've reinstalled xampp 3 times but still, I'm getting this same error -

**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0**

[Please open this to see my phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJLz9.png)

I am using Laravel 8, PHP 7.4 and window 10 64x.

I'd be very thankful if anyone could help me

Comment: My personal recommendation is to stop using XAMPP and use another approach as (if you have Windows 10 Pro), you can use WSL and Docker... Stop using XAMPP as it is not professional and you will not learn anything with it, you will only get this type of headaches. Also, there are plenty of tutorials to help you setup WSL and Docker...

Comment: It would be helpful we knew what the 'most solutions' you tried were. The 'not a valid' application error is common if you have installed Instant Client 64 bit but PHP is 32-bit.  Or vice versa. Using a different PHP build isn't going to overcome this error.  Take a look at https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database

Comment: @ChristopherJones My php and instant client both are 64-bit, I've checked it properly and I also have followed this blog post,  but did not worked for me

Comment: Since something is obviously wrong, update your post with how you actually checked - and the results - so that we can cross-check and help you.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I checked with phpinfo, you can see it

Comment: Now you need to check & prove that the Oracle client libraries being used are 64-bit.  If you have multiple Oracle versions or products installed, checking this will require care.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, elaborate a little, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting my time for 10 days, I finally found a solution.

1. Download both `Instant Client Package – Basic` and `Instant Client Package – SDK`, this is where most of us do miskates, we only download basic package.
   Repeating again, download both basic and SDK packages.
2. Unzip them into `c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1` and `c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk` respectively.

Note - if these folder locations don't work for you, check in your `phpinfo > Configure Command` and unzip into that location. In my case, it did work.

3. Now add `c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1` this location in your environment variable path.
4. Restart your computer.

I hope this worked for you.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it . Where the files are placed doesn't matter.  The important thing is  to set PATH to the directory with oci.dll.  Since you're on Windows and using PHP's pre-built oci8 DLL, you don't need the SDK (which has header files for building such DLLs).

Comment: No, I'd set the PATH properly, but it only worked after downloading SDK, I don't know the reason. And thank you so much for your help.